# How to use OCaml Url and Cohttp

Tags: json, api, http, url, ocaml

I am trying to use OCaml's Url and Cohttp modules in order to access an API and retrieve JSON data. I am NOT trying to do this in an asynchronous way. I have no experience with web/network programming and all of the module documentation just gives signatures for types and methods (not much help to me since I do not know what they do). I am trying to access the bitstamp API and retrieve the bid price for a bitcoin. So far I only know how to declare a URI

```
    let bitstamp_uri = Uri.of_string "http://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/";;
```

but I do now know how to make a call to the uri in order to retrieve the json data. How can I use existing libraries to accomplish this? I already know how to parse json data into types that I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cohttp requires you to either use Lwt or Async, so you'll have to learn one of these libraries. Luckily, retrieving JSON text and parsing it is exactly one of the examples in the new Real World OCaml book, which you can read free online [here](http://realworldocaml.org). Chapter 18 covers Async and Cohttp and Chapter 15 covers JSON parsing.

Now, to actually answer your question:

```
$ utop
utop # #require "lwt.syntax";;
utop # #require "core";;
utop # open Core.Std;;
utop # #require "cohttp.lwt";;
utop # #require "uri";;

utop # let get_uri uri : string Or_error.t Lwt.t =
  let open Lwt in
  match_lwt Cohttp_lwt_unix.Client.get uri with
  | None ->
    let msg = sprintf "%s: no reply" (Uri.to_string uri) in
    return (Or_error.error_string msg)
  | Some (_, body) -> (
      lwt body = Cohttp_lwt_body.string_of_body body in
      return (Ok body)
    );;

utop # let bitstamp_uri = Uri.of_string "http://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/";;

utop # get_uri bitstamp_uri;;
- : string Or_error.t =
Core_kernel.Result.Ok
"{\"high\": \"755.00\", \"last\": \"675.20\", \"timestamp\": \"1384841189\", \"bid\": \"675.10\", \"volume\": \"72858.24608402\", \"low\": \"471.26\", \"ask\": \"675.20\"}"
```

I used Core and Lwt in this case. The RWO book uses Async. If you want to avoid the complexity of asynchronous programming completely, then you cannot use Cohttp.

Comment: Thanks this helps out alot, however I cannot find the module Cohttp_lwt_unix (I do have cohttp installed). Also, I cannot find any good documentation/examples for all of the methods in cohttp. I have created the html via ocamldoc and it seem incomplete. Do you know where I can get some more information on this?

Comment: Cohttp is split into 3 ocamlfind packages: `ocamlfind list | grep cohttp`. Be sure to load `cohttp.lwt` to use the lwt modules. This is because most apps will either use Async or Lwt, not both. This way you don't have to load all of Async if you're using Lwt, and vice versa.

Comment: Regarding documentation, I'm only aware of the chapter in Real World OCaml that I mentioned. OCamldoc often fails on complex code; it is easier to read the mli files directly. Unfortunately, there isn't much else.

Comment: When I run `$ ocamlfind list | grep cohttp` the only results returned are `cohttp` and `cohttp.async`. I have tried to find `cohttp.lwt` but I cannot find the source anywhere and it does not seem to be available on opam. Do you know where I can get it from?    EDIT: I found the source files on github, however I am not sure how/where to save them because I already have Async, Cohttp and Lwt directories in my `.opam/system/lib` directory.

Comment: Just do `opam install lwt`. This will automatically also upgrade your cohttp installation to include `cohttp.lwt`. Since cohttp can be used with async or lwt, its opam package was designed to let you install it when you have either or both of these prerequisites installed.

Comment: I ran `opam install lwt` and the only message I receive is `Package lwt is already installed (current version is 2.4.4)`. Maybe I can compile these from source.

Comment: These are commonly used libraries and opam should be installing them correctly. If `lwt` is already installed, I'm not sure why `cohttp.lwt` isn't. You could try `opam remove cohttp` and then `opam install lwt cohttp` just to give it a fresh try.

Comment: Also, when did you last do `opam update` and `opam upgrade`. Try that in case you've got a very old package list.

Comment: I ran `opam update` and `opam upgrade` today, I also deleted the entire `/.opam/` directory and reinstalled all of the packages that I use and it still does not work. I also downloaded the source from github and tried compiling it but that is not working. I am at a loss right now.

Comment: I'm at a loss too. This is well beyond the original question. Please post to the Platform list (http://lists.ocaml.org/listinfo/platform) for general OPAM questions. Provide your OS, any messages you're getting, etc., and we'll try to help you there.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an answer using `Curl`, which doesn't require you to understand Async. (For the record, I think you're better off using Async and Cohttp, though!)

```
(* Wrapper for Curl. Used by the function below. *)
let fetch (url: string) (f: string -> int): unit =
  let c = Curl.init () in
  Curl.set_url c url;
  Curl.set_followlocation c true;
  Curl.set_writefunction c f;
  Curl.perform c;
  Curl.cleanup c
;;

(* [get url] fetches the document at [url] and returns its contents as a string. *)
let get (url: string): string =
  let buf = Buffer.create 16 in
  fetch url (fun s -> Buffer.add_string buf s; String.length s);
  Buffer.contents buf
;;
```

Comment: I guess I wanted the example to be more self-contained? But yeah, definitely, `Buffer` makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
utop [0]: #require "async";;
utop [1]: #require "cohttp.async";;
utop [2]: open Async.Std;;
utop [3]:  let get_uri uri_str = Cohttp_async.Client.get @@ Uri.of_string uri_str
>>= fun (_, body) -> Cohttp_async.Body.to_string body;;
val get_uri : string -> string Deferred.t = <fun>
utop [4]: get_uri "http://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/";;
- : string = "{\"high\": \"661.11\", \"last\": \"652.65\", \"timestamp\": 
\"1402207587\", \"bid\": \"651.99\", \"vwap\": \"654.52\", \"volume\": 
\"3022.07902416\", \"low\": \"648.87\", \"ask\": \"654.29\"}"
```

takes me a while to figure it out, so I just post the code here.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another example that you may find useful. I don't depend on Core or Async in this example, and you should be able to run it as a script rather than in a toplevel.

```
#! /usr/bin/env ocaml

#use "topfind"
#require "uri"
#require "cohttp.lwt"

let fetch uri =
  let open Lwt in
  Cohttp_lwt_unix.Client.get uri >>= fun (resp, body) ->
  Cohttp_lwt_body.to_string body >>= fun b ->
  Lwt_io.printl b

let () =
  let bitstamp_uri = Uri.of_string "http://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/" in
  Lwt_main.run (fetch bitstamp_uri)
```